# How can I initialize a Doubly Linked List and then add the first element in java?

Tags: java, nodes, doubly-linked-list

I'm currently working on creating a doubly linked list, but I'm struggling to do so because the constructor requires the previous element and the next element. However, checking the list just results in two null elements, the head and the tail. The constructor for a node is

```
    public Node(Node prev, Node next, String link) {
        this.prev = prev;
        this.next = next;
        this.link = link;
    }
```

The constructor for the empty list that I have is

```
public DoublyLinkedList() {
    head = tail = null;
}
```

My code for adding an element is

```
public void addElement(String link) {
    Node n = new Node(tail.prev, tail, link);
    if (head == null) {
        head = n;
        head.next = n;
    }
    tail.prev = n;
    tail = n;
}
```

I know that the reason I'm resulting in null is because tail == null when I pass it into the constructor. However, I don't know how to update the value of tail before creating a new Node. I tried constructing the empty list with

```
public DoublyLinkedList() {
    head = tail = null;
    head.prev = null;
    head.next = tail;
    tail.next = null;
    tail.prev = head;
}
```

But that isn't showing the elements as being added either.

Comment: Without a clear definition of what "isn't working" means, we cannot help you.

Comment: @JoeC I put in the post, when I try to actually check the list I just get null elements, the head and the tail. I edited for clarity.

Comment: It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a more specific question.

Comment: I know how to use a debugger. I'm asking why, when I print the list, it simply prints one element: null.

Comment: Where is the print statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am going to assume that `addElement` adds an element to the end of the list
if that is the case try this instead

```
Node n = new Node(tail, null, link); // The new tail
if (head == null) {
    head = n;
    tail = n;
}else{
    tail.next = n;
    tail = n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For that you can create a class like this:
Just for start.

```
public class DLinkedList{
  private node pHead;
  private node pTail;

  public DLinkedList()
  {
      this.pHead=null;
      this.pTail=null;
  }

   public insert(String newLink)
   {
       node newNode = new node():
       newNode.link = newLink;
       if(pHead==null)
       {
          pHead=newNode;
          pTail=pHead;
      }
      else
      {
          newNode.prev=pTail;
          pTail.next=newNode;
          pTail= pTail.next;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm not at home, so i made this in a cellphone. Sorry for not made more to help

Comment: Lists is something I love to use. Usually I do it in C